# Declined spam flag on clickbait question

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, spam

I'm curious as to why the spam flag that I raised on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522181/how-do-i-created-a-modified-version-of-an-app) was declined. The entire body of the question reads:

> I launched a website few days ago. Its about Deezer music. So I need
> an modified version of Deezer Music which called [Deezer Premium Apk
> iOS](https://www.example.com/) How can I do it?

The implication of the question is that OP needs a product to make their website work, but in fact the linked product is their own (the link in the question goes to the same link as on the poster's profile). That to me is essentially undisclosed affiliation. Additionally, there is no information in the question other than that, so it would seem the sole intention of the question is to get people to click on the link. The linked website's purpose is to get users to download a product (Deezer Premium).

This seems to me to meet the criteria necessary to be flagged as spam. To avoid further declined flags, I'd like to understand why it doesn't.

Comment: I have no idea. Handled now...

Comment: Seems to have confused another user into thinking it is a legitimate question... Perhaps too much time on the site has caused these other users' quality standards to be diminished...

Comment: @CodyGray I don't understand what that is a reference to. Are saying someone posted an Answer or someone upvoted it or someone just flagged it for closure instead of flagging it as spam getting their flag declined too? Or something else?

Comment: basically it says, we are all only human and make misstakes

Comment: @Scraffe: It's a reference to a lot of trash (zero effort / zero understanding) questions being allowed to stay that in the former days would have been closed and deleted.  All in the name of being welcoming to new users who don't care about the posting guidelines, did not read them, and did not bother to even type their own question title into the site search or google search which would have found five existing SO questions which are better-written and which are already answered.

Comment: This is honestly why I'm wary of the spam flag. I see very, very little outright spam, more likely URLs disguised in a legitimate question like your example - and those I flag with spam get often declined, even though the question seems to get deleted by the handler/mod (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440307). I understand the flag targets specifically spam posts (as in outright advertisement), but what else for suspicious links, a custom flag?

Comment: @Lennart: For something like that, I'd say keep flagging as spam and reach out to the mods if any flags on such posts get declined. What you have there is a textbook example of thinly disguised linkspam — the non-sequitur "sonoma website design" link text is an obvious give-away.

Comment: Is the trouble that the spam flag doesn't give you a chance to explain why it is spam?  I would tend to use a custom flag and start the explanation with `Spam:` and an explanation of  why I think it is spam.  That would help the (overworked) moderators understand what you've seen and why it is spam.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's not a bad idea, the only issue is that custom flags tend to be handled fairly slowly due to the fact that moderators are overworked, and ideally spam should be removed from the site as soon as practical.

Comment: @Nick — So, should we suggest "The spam flag option should allow (require?) a comment (like the "needs moderator attention flag") to explain why the post is spam"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think require is necessary; a lot of spam seems fairly obvious, but certainly allowing a comment could be helpful.

Comment: Never thought clickbait would be a thing in SO. I'm so wrong.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 well, I tried to get rid of it quickly! :)

Comment: The question is why Makyen undeleted the spam question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64522181/timeline

Comment: I was expecting a meta post on a question with a vague but enticing title, but instead got a post on ordinary spam. I feel ... clickbaited?

Comment: @CrisLuengo indeed. I suspect they might be the person who can answer this question.

Comment: The irony is this meta post being on "Hot Posts", exposed to everyone who opens StackOverflow today. If this is a super elaborated two parts spam post, congratulations.

Comment: @lvella You know that only 10K'ers can see that post, right?

Comment: @Scratte There is no need. The text is quoted in its entirety here, and while the link is fake, the original target is spelled out.

Comment: @lvella you raise a good point, and I have edited out the URL from the text. Although it is obviously still in the revision history it at least is not immediately obvious.

Comment: @CrisLuengo My crystal ball says that Makyen was trying to ensure that Nick's initial spam flag was marked as "disputed", rather than "declined".

Comment: @Scratte It was a reference to *someone* having posted a comment on that question. My reading of that comment was that the author thought it was a legitimately-asked question. Maybe not, but why waste time giving guidance to spammers about their question being "a little too broad"?

Comment: @CodyGray that makes sense... and indeed that is what happened (for which I am truly appreciative)

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, that someone was indeed me. I posted that when I flagged it. I always try to give a reason. I didn't flag it as spam, because I **wasn't sure**. Assume good faith and all that. Alternatively I could have let it be.. not flagged it at all. Pretend I didn't see and let someone else deal with it. "a little too broad" is just my most polite way of saying "Are you kidding me?!? You seriously want someone to expand on your website?!? Why would anyone even want to visit it?!?". Ironically it seems I'm one of the few users that actually didn't click on that link ;)

Comment: All that understatement... who knew @Scratte was British?

Comment: I can understand why someone would err on the side of caution. Spam has a fairly hefty penalty attached and could result in the poster's account taking a shot from the Wave Motion Cannon.

Answer (score 95):

That looks like a classic example of a spam post disguised as a legit question.

Apparently in this case the disguise worked, since according to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64522181/timeline) (10k+ only) the question passed first post review, received a comment from a user saying it was "a little too broad for a Question on Stack Overflow", was closed by three other users as "needs more focus" and apparently even had a spam flag on it declined by a moderator.

I don't see much we can really do to prevent such spam from slipping through in the future, except to spread awareness of the fact that such disguised spam exists and teach users (and moderators!) how to identify it.

In this specific case, a number of hints — each only suggestive on its own — combine to make a good case that this was never an actual question asked in good faith:

- The asker is a brand new user with no previous questions or answers.  (Spammer accounts almost always are, which is one reason why first post review exists.  Of course, so are many legit users too, so this alone proves nothing.  But it's one clue among many.)
- It's a short question with a single link in it.  (The people hired to post such spam don't want to spend more than a bare minimum of time writing it, so the posts rarely have much detail.)
- The link text is stuffed full of search keywords.  (The goal of this kind of spam is to stuff Google's index so that the linked site will rank higher for those keywords.)
- The link URL is also keyword-stuffed, and points to a site whose domain name matches the product apparently being promoted in the keywords, rather than to some well known and established site like Github or Wikipedia or developer.android.com or something else that you'd *expect* to see linked on SO.
- If you actually open the linked page (which I did, since I trust NoScript to keep it from messing with my browser), it's clearly promotional and appears to be trying to convince you to install some software of questionable legality from a non-standard source.
- Looking more closely, the "name" of the software in the link text makes little sense except as an attempt at keyword stuffing: while people Googling for software for their phone may well include "apk" or "ios" in their search string, why would a legitimate software product include either of those keywords — let alone both of them together! — in its name?
- The question text also doesn't make much sense when looked at more closely: why is some random person developing a website about a commercial music player, and why would that make them need a hacked version of the player on their phone?  (Even if that was a genuine question, the whole thing would seem rather shady.  But most likely the spammer just filled in the blanks on a generic forum post template like "*I just launched a website. It's about <TOPIC>. So I need <DESCRIPTION>, which is called <SPAM LINK>. How can I do it?*")
- Even if this was a genuine question, rather than thinly disguised spam, it would still be blatantly off-topic on SO for several reasons: not only is it far too vague to be answerable, but the only part of it that even relates to programming in any way is the title.  (This is also typical of spam posts, since the people writing them don't want to spend extra time tailoring them to each target site or even reading the site's documentation to find out what's on-topic where.)
- In general, the question is very vague and often muddled, so that it's hard to tell what it's asking about.  (This is deliberate: if the question was clearly written, it'd be clear that it doesn't belong on SO and/or that the link is not pertinent.  But when it's sufficiently vague and confusing, it becomes possible for someone to charitably assume that it *might* be a legitimate question that just needs clarification, and that the link might *somehow* be relevant, increasing its chances of survival.)

While none of these things *alone* is sufficient to prove that the question is spam (although, spam or not, it should at least be obvious that it's not even remotely a salvageable on-topic question for SO), with them all put together, the likelihood of this being spam is IMO at least 99.9%.

Note that a post may still be spam even if it doesn't tick all the boxes above.  In particular, not all spam posts even have links!  Some have telephone numbers instead, trying to convince Google to suggest those numbers when people search for keywords in the post.  Others may be "spam seeds" that look harmless (although usually still low quality and off-topic) on their own, often asking something like "*Where can I find/buy/download <THING>?*", but will shortly afterwards receive an answer from another spammer account that actually contains the spam link.

Anyway, what can you* do if you find such a spam post?

- First, flag it as spam, as you did in this case.
- To make sure that it gets promptly flagged and nuked, you can report it in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).  They even have [a standard format for such reports](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests).  Do make sure that [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/) or one of the other [bots](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests) active there didn't already report it.
- If Smokey failed to catch the spam post (as appears to have happened here), consider asking someone with the appropriate [privilege](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/Privileges#smokedetector-privileges-sd) to report it directly to the bot.  There will most likely be someone in SOCVR at any time who can do it.  You can also ask to [be given reporting privileges](https://charcoal-se.org/training/privileges) yourself.
- In any case, keep an eye on the post and make sure it gets promptly deleted, not just closed, preferably before it gets indexed by Google.  The people hired to spam such links typically only get paid after presenting proof that their post was successful, so the faster such spam gets deleted, the less likely they are to get rewarded for it and the less attractive SO becomes as a spam target.

In the unlikely case that your spam flag gets declined, as apparently happened here, contact the moderators and explain why you think the post really is spam.  Posting on meta, as you did, is a perfectly good way to do that.  Alternatively, you could've also tried casting a second custom flag on the post and explained the issue there, or contacted a mod via SE chat.

In any case, reporting a post like this as spam via SOCVR and/or Smokey should get it promptly reviewed and flagged by people active in the chat room, most likely getting it deleted automatically after six spam flags without even requiring moderator involvement.

---

<sup>*) Generic "you", referring to anyone who reads this answer.</sup>

Comment: "the question passed first post review" I was the one who reviewed it in First Posts and [asked in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50773132#50773132) if it was spam. I flagged it as "Needs details or clarity" only for the very reason that this question was necessary (fearing a declined flag if the spam is not obvious). The OP then shortly afterwards concluded it was spam, but their flag was declined.

Comment: I'm guessing @JeanneDark means the author of this meta post, not the author of the Question in question :) I was the one that left the comment, and I also flagged the post as "Needs details or clarity". Which I did *because* it was discussed in the chatroom. Being a spam-detector is not my profession, and will likely never be. The advice has always been to *only* use the spam flag  when one is sure, which I wasn't. To be honest, I'm quite happy I didn't, as that would have added to my declined flag count.

Comment: Yes, with OP I mean the author of this MSO question. To expand on what @Scratte said, I'm also only using the spam flag if I'm sure and it's obvious. I've one declined flag and it was a short, very low quality [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050872/white-bars-in-both-sides-on-my-site-plis) with a link and username that, together with the overall look of the question, appeared very dubious to me (it was then quickly closed and deleted via delete votes). That's why I became more careful.

Comment: Nicely written post - I should have had as much detail in the question. As has been pointed out in the comments, we did discuss this in SOCVR, although I did make the mistake of simply commenting that I had flagged it as spam, rather than raising a flag request, which would likely have resulted in the post being deleted as spam and making this entire Q&A unnecessary.

Comment: @JeanneDark: Yeah, I can see how [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64050872) could be a false positive. To me, the biggest signs that it's probably _not_ disguised spam are that 1) the user clearly admits that it's their site, 2) there are no signs of keyword stuffing, 3) the question is about developing said web site, so the link has an excuse for being there, and 4) it actually describes a specific programming (well, UI styling) problem. Sure, it's still close-worthy since it includes no on-site reproducible example, but it's otherwise clear enough. Spam rarely is.

Comment: A minor clarification: SOCVR is indeed a place to help delete spam, but if you want to get it into Smoke Detector the better place to ask is [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), which is where Smoke Detector is operated. If you suspect there's a **pattern**, you have to mention it there because SOCVR has a strict rule against discussing users